# ¿en php con la libreria SpreadsheetReader se puede leer el color de la celda de excel?

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

Estoy leyendo el contenido de un `Excel` con la librería `SpreadsheetReader` y quiero saber si es posible saber el color de las celdas de `Excel`.

Debido a que manejo color azul aprobado y amarillo pendiente y me gustaría poder saber cuales son amarillas y cuales son azules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si, podes hacerlo así:

```
$inputFileName = './example1.xls';
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet(); // Obtenes la referencia a la hoja
$cell = $sheet->getCell('A1'); // Seleccionas la celda
$cellStyle = $cell->getStyle(); // Accedes a los estilos

// Finalmente podes obtener el color de fondo en RGB (red, green, blue)
$color = $cellStyle->getFill()->getStartColor()->getRGB();  // Ejemplo: FFFFFF
// o en ARGB (alpha, red, green, blue)
$color = $cellStyle->getFill()->getStartColor()->getARGB(); // Ejemplo: FFFFFFFF
```

---

Referencias:

- [PhpSpreadsheet's documentation - Formatting cells](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#formatting-cells)